# Function Does Not Recognize Array Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

I tried to create an array via parsing a .csv file Then I run it through the this function.

```
//Array

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"499CSV" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *csvString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSArray *locations = [csvString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

NSMutableArray *secondArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString * location in locations)
{

NSArray *components = [location componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

double latitude   = [components[0] doubleValue];
double longitude  = [components[1] doubleValue];
NSString *station =  components[2];

NSDictionary *dict = @{@"kLatitude": @(latitude),
                       @"kLongitude": @(longitude),
                       @"kStation": station};

[secondArray addObject:dict];

}

//Comes Out

secondArray = (
    {
    kLatitude = "41.656467";
    kLongitude = "-81.277963";
    kStation = 27200;
},
    {
    kLatitude = "41.657118";
    kLongitude = "-81.276545";
    kStation = 27650;
},
    {
    kLatitude = "41.658493";
    kLongitude = "-81.27354200000001";
    kStation = 28632;
}...


//function

NSArray *orderedPlaces = [locationsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a,id b) {

NSDictionary *dictA;
NSDictionary *dictB;
CLLocation *locA;
CLLocation *locB;

dictA = (NSDictionary *)a;
dictB = (NSDictionary *)b;
locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[dictA objectForKey:kLatitude] doubleValue]longitude:[[dictA objectForKey:kLongitude] doubleValue]];
locB = [[CLLocation alloc]
        initWithLatitude:[[dictB objectForKey:kLatitude] doubleValue]
        longitude:[[dictB objectForKey:kLongitude] doubleValue]];
```

Problem is that the function does not recognize the array values. I guess it has something to do with how I define the values. Specifically, the call to kLatitude and kLongitude.

Can someone identify why my function does not read the secondArray values like it does the firstArray values? And how I can fix it? Thanks in advance for you time.

Comment: What's the difference? I don't see it.

Comment: I updated my question to better explain the problem. Please review.

Comment: You lie.  The first output listing could not have occurred with those `#define` statements visible.  And if they're not visible you couldn't have constructed your array the way you said you did.  Please post the REAL CODE and REAL OUTPUT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined your dictionary keys:

```
#define kStation @"station"
#define kLatitude @"latitude"
#define kLongitude @"longitude"
```

try:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{kLatitude : @(latitude),
                       kLongitude: @(longitude),
                       kStation  : station};
```

You use them in your first array creation, but not in the second.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code,**

*1) It's always better to deal with the keys you have defined,*
*2) Before getting the double Values, Make sure you don't have white spaces and newline characters in that string*

```
NSCharacterSet *whiteSPNewLine = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    for (NSString * location in locations)
    {

        NSArray *components = [location componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        double latitude   = [[components[0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whiteSPNewLine] doubleValue];
        double longitude  = [[components[1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whiteSPNewLine] doubleValue];
        NSString *station = [components[2] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whiteSPNewLine];

        NSDictionary *dict = @{kLatitude: @(latitude),
                               kLongitude: @(longitude),
                               kStation: station};

        [secondArray addObject:dict];

    }
```